# Twitter Bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been freaking out for two days with this...

I've set up a page with the Bootstrap CSS, with the following code in the page head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openclassifieds.googlecode.com/svn-history/r119/branches/2.0/themes/twitter/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openclassifieds.googlecode.com/svn-history/r119/branches/2.0/themes/twitter/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openclassifieds.googlecode.com/svn-history/r119/branches/2.0/themes/twitter/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

In my body I have this:

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-signin" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true">Launch Modal</button>

<div id="modal-signin" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h2>Sign in <small>or sign up</small></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Teste</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the Bootstrap docs this is what I have to do to get this working but when I click the button it doesn't do anything...
I don't know what the problem is...
I need urgent help

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery will need to be included first as the twitter bootstrap depends on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openclassifieds.googlecode.com/svn-history/r119/branches/2.0/themes/twitter/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openclassifieds.googlecode.com/svn-history/r119/branches/2.0/themes/twitter/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openclassifieds.googlecode.com/svn-history/r119/branches/2.0/themes/twitter/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
```